# Searching for a specific entity(a specific bank) using Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am working on this android application of finding specific banks(by their names) nearby using Google maps API and i am stuck since am not sure how to do that. I have created a custom list and a map fragment getting the current location.From the custom list is a list of banks say Barclays. How do i get barclays banks around me on the map when a click it on the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this and it will work for your case.

```js
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-1.2833,36.8167&radius=5000&types=bank&name=barclays&key=YOUR API KEY
```

This searches all places of type bank with the word barclays in their name around  Nairobi Kenya within a radius of 5km

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Google Places https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Comment: thank you Lance Toth i have just cracked it! actually i wasn't seeing the part with the name